# How to delete multiple rows with two columns as composite primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know what is the correct way to delete multiple records from a table with two columns as a composite primary key. My table has the `Id` and `Year` columns as a composite primary key and I have tried the following but I would like to see more opinions because I think there are better ways to do it and improve my code

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Id, Year 
              FROM Table
              WHERE Age < 18)
```

```
DELETE * FROM Table
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Table
             WHERE Age  < 18)
  AND Year IN (SELECT Year FROM Table
               WHERE Age  < 18)
```

I also found this example but this syntax doesn't seem to work in SQL Server, is there something similar that I can use?

```
DELETE FROM cpi
WHERE (countryid, year) IN (('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992))
```

Comment: I suspect that both of those queries would delete every row you in your table. Certainly the first one would if anyone in the table is under the age of 18. If that is your goal, what's wrong with just `DELETE FROM [Table];` or even `TRUNCATE TABLE [Table];`? I think we're missing you're real goal here.

Comment: Are you trying to delete *duplicates*? Can you show some rows in the table _before_ the delete (both rows you want to delete and rows you're going to keep), and identify which rows should be deleted? "These queries didn't work" is hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` and `or` for you last example.

```
DELETE FROM cpi
    WHERE (countryid = 'AD' AND year = 2010) OR
          (countryid = 'AF' AND year = 2009) OR
          (countryid = 'AG' AND year = 1992)
```

I'm not sure how this applies to your earlier examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
DELETE FROM [Table]
WHERE Age < 18
```